# Java printwriter

Tags: java

I have a proxy class, that receives a request and send the request to another server and gets the response and directs it back to original requestor. I use a socket to connect to the server and use Printwriter to write to it. 
Something like this

```
    private PrintWriter out;

    public void writeString( String message ) throws IOException {
        openStreams();
        out.print( message);
        out.flush();
    }
```

I start the proxy and send request to server via proxy. The problem is I see a lot of these request/response in the console of the proxy. Is there is a different way of doing this, where the console is left cleaner. I am new to socket programing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code does not show at all how you get output on the console of the proxy. It is possible to have a networking program that does not output anything, yes.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. In particular what does this mean: "The problem is I see a lot of these request/response in the console of the proxy." Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a System.out.println or debug logging statement somewhere else in your code. Do a quick text-search through your various java files and search for System.out statements. If you are using some logging framework like log4j/slf4j, check if you are logging something at an inappropriate level (info instead of debug maybe) and tune your logger config to appropriate lever and/or log to file instead of console.

Comment: How silly of me!! you are right!! Thanks a lot.. LOL!! Can't believe I did this!!

Comment: Hehe, don't feel too bad. One of the most common mistakes.